# Save, Open and Sort Excel attachments from a macro in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive reports via outlook every 15 minutes. These reports actually come in Excel      attachments. I only work 8 hours a day; the next day I usually have a build up of reports that have come every 15 minutes since the previous day.  I have to then open each report individually and then sort them by header.

I know how to open and save each unread email attachment and save it on to my computer:

```
         Sub GetAttachments()
             On Error GoTo GetAttachments_err
             Dim ns As NameSpace
             Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
             Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
             Dim Item As Object
             Dim Atmt As Attachment
             Dim FileName As String
             Dim i As Integer

             Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
             Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
             Set Mailbox = Inbox.Parent
             Set SubFolder = Mailbox.Folders("Local Archive")
             i = 0

             'check if there is any mail in the folder'
              If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
              MsgBox "There are no messages in the folder.", vbInformation, _
                 "Nothing Found"
               Exit Sub
               End If

          'Check each message and save the attachment'
            If SubFolder.Items.Count > 0 Then
              For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
                 If Item.UnRead = True Then
                     For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                      FileName = "C:\Users\badana\Desktop\" & Atmt.FileName
                      Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName 'saves each attachment'

                      'this code opens each attachment'
                       Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                       myShell.Run FileName

                       'this sets the email as read'
                        Item.UnRead = False
                       'updates the counter'
                       i = i + 1

                        Next Atmt
                  End If
              Next Item
            End If

  'Display results

  If i > 0 Then
   MsgBox "I found " & i & " attached files." _
   & vbCrLf & "They are saved on your desktop" _
   & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Have a nice day.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
   Else
 MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, _
 "Finished!"
 End If

       'Replenish Memory'
        GetAttachments_exit:

       Set Atmt = Nothing
       Set Item = Nothing
       Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub

 'function for sorting the excel attachment'


  GetAttachments_err:
  MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
  & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
  & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
  & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
  & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
  , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume GetAttachments_exit
 End Sub
```

I have the code for sorting each attachment by header:

```
Sub SortData()
'
' SortData Macro
' sorts data
'

'
  Dim lngLast As Long
  lngLast = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  Cells.Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("02APR14").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("02APR14").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & lngLast) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("02APR14").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("K2:K" & lngLast) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("02APR14").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:L" & lngLast)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
  End With
 End Sub
```

However, I want to be able to combine both codes in outlook such that I can run it as          one macro from outlook, it will open and save every attachment and also sort them in one go. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your sort data macro, and edited it a little to open a file when given a filename.

You'll need to call this from within your outlook macro, using the filename of the attachment you just saved. eg. Delete these lines from your savedown code:

```
Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myShell.Run FileName
```

and replace with:

```
openAndSort(FileName)
```

The following code can be added in the same module in outlook vba. It uses early binding, so you'll need to add a reference to the excel object library (tools->references->microsoft excel 14 object library)

```
Sub openAndSort(filename As String)
'
'
'
'
Dim lngLast As Long

Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
Set xl = New Excel.Application
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set sh = wb.Worksheets("02APR14")
xl.Visible = True
  lngLast = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

sh.Sort.SortFields.Clear
sh.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=sh.Range("A2:A" & lngLast) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
sh.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=sh.Range("K2:K" & lngLast) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With sh.Sort
    .SetRange sh.Range("A1:L" & lngLast)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

wb.Save
wb.Close
Set wb = Nothing
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
End Sub
```